# img tag with external insecure src not downloaded

Tags: php, html, linux, ssl

I'm using an external api to create an image (chart) dynamically based on the data retrieved from the database.

```
<img src="https://apiurl?dynamic-variables" />
```

It is working perfectly in my localhost but in the server images are not shown.
When I try curl I get this error message: curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired.

how to bypass ssl check and get the images?

Comment: Does `curl -k` work?

Comment: @dibery it shows not found 404

Comment: How did you issue the `curl` command? Just add a `-k` option.

Comment: @dibery curl -k <image-url>

Comment: What if you paste the url in a browser?

Comment: @dibery it works in browser

Comment: Get `curl` command from dev tool - network.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but is your Server running with an LetsEncrypt certificate? https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

You could also try to run `sudo certbot` to renew the server certificate if it is one.

Comment: the issue is not from my website certificate. the external website certificate is not renewed

Comment: Did you alreday told/contacted the webmaster of `https://apiurl?dynamic-variables` that their certificate has expired?